# Why would values be different in SSRS vs. SLQ using the ROUND function?

Tags: reporting-services

Using SQL, I type in this SELECT 14.75 * 22.35 and get this result 329.6625. Then I use
SELECT ROUND(329.6625,2) and get 329.6600.  In SSRS I am using this as my expression:

=round(Fields!v_earnhrs.Value*Fields!actl_hrly.Value,2)   where v.earnhrs is 14.75 and actl.hrly is 22.35.

When I run the SSRS report, the value from the expression shows as 329.67. Why the difference, and how to get the SSRS column value to be the same as SQL shows?  Thank you.

Comment: What result do you get in SSRS if you don't use `round()`?

Comment: If I don't round it, it is 329.6625 in SQL.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Edit your question and show SQL datatypes for both columns and also show if there is any formatting in the report etc. What versions are you using? You could try to force the rounding method with something like `=System.Math.ROUND(Fields!v_earnhrs.Value * Fields!actl_hrly.Value, 2, System.MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`